# Calculate the mid and quarter position in post processer

Tags: jmeter

From the response header I am fetching this the total number of records, and I want to fetch the mid position and quarter position using the total records,

[image: Fetching the total number]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it is quite easy,
Please add a `JSR223 postprocessor` with the following code,

```
def int initialValue = 0;
def finalValue = vars.get("TotalNumberOfRecords") as Integer;

def int middleValue = Math.round((initialValue+finalValue)/2) as Integer;
def int quarterValue = Math.round((initialValue+middleValue)/2) as Integer;

vars.put('positionMid',Integer.toString(middleValue))
vars.put('positionQuarter', Integer.toString(quarterValue))
```

Comment: why you need `initialValue`?

Comment: Ah, yeah actually we don't need it. If the mid is for the value which is retrieved is single it would be always 0 as the initial value.